# Cache storage increasing so much using Ionic 3. Causing Quota Exceeded Error

Tags: angular, ionic3, quota, progressive-web-apps, cachestorage

I developed several PWA apps using Ionic.

Each time I reload a page of the app, in the browser, the size of cache storage is increased. And it is not cleaned. It can achieve up to several GBs of space which eventually causes a Quota Exceeded Error.

How can I avoid this excessive use of cache in my app?

Answer (score 0):

What are you storing in the Localstorage? Because I think you have a limit. You you can use only up to 10mb or 50mb of storage depending on the type of the storage.

Answer (score 0):

What is being stored in the cache storage is the cache handled by the service worker.